# Issue with object within an object in react-native: Undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an object that I read into state. When I tried to extract a value from within that object in render I get an error saying "undefined is not an object".

So the object looks like this: const currentGrid = {size: {cols: "15", rows: "15"}}

I assign it to state with this.setState({ currentGrid: currentGrid }) in componentWillMount.

In render I do this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <List>
            <ListItem>
              <Body>
                <Text>{this.state.currentGrid.size.cols}</Text>
              </Body>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Content>
</Container>
);
}
```

When I load the component I get "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.currentGrid.size.cols')

I know that the object is set in state. If I leave off "cols" the error is:

Invariant: Objects are not valid as React child (found: object with keys {cols, rows}). If you meant to render a collection of children use an Array instead.

Sorry if this is a common error, but I can't find how to do it properly unless I have to convert this embedded object into an array, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Could you show more of your code? The probably might be with how you're setting currentGrid

Answer (score 0):

One possibility here is the first time the app runs `currentGrid` is undefined. In your render check if it exist before rendering text

```
render() {
 return (
  <Container>
    <Content>
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <Body>
            {this.state.currentGrid.size && (
              <Text>{this.state.currentGrid.size.cols}</Text>
            )}
          </Body>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </Content>
  </Container>
 );
}
```